# Is it possible to feed a relative URL to Phantom.js page generator to get a PDF render?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pdf-generation, phantomjs

What I currently have is this script:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function(phantomInstance) {
    phantomInstance.createPage(function(page) {
        page.set('paperSize', {
            format: 'A4',
            orientation: 'portrait',
            margin: '1cm'
        });
        page.open('https://blablabla.c9.io/pdf/' + data._id + data.querystring, function(status) {
            page.render('client/pdf/' + data._id + '.pdf', function() {
                phantomInstance.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I read in Phantom.js docs that `page.open`'s first param has to be absolute URL. It's not very comfortable since I have two environments that have this script running (one dev on Cloud9 IDE, one prod on VPS).

Is there a better way to deal with this restriction, and is there a way to operate relative URLs without having URL base managed by hand (e.g. `page.open(baseUrl + '...', ...)`)?

I use Express over Node.js server on both environments, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

No, and I don't see any considerable problems with generating your url on the fly (e.g. `page.open(baseUrl + '...', ...)`).

You could create your own little wrapper, but will need to feed the baseUrl and relative path into it somehow which might make your life a little easier in the short term, but might be counterproductive in the long term when you need to refactor.